# I spliced Raspbian and Kali by accident... should I be worried?

Tags: ssh, security, http, kali-linux, raspbian

So, I recently got a Raspberry Pi. I installed Raspbian Wheezy on it immediately, got it all set up with SSH and VNC, and ready to go. One day I decided that it would be a brilliant idea to install Kali on it (friend had suggested it for whatever reason; I later decided against for obvious reasons). And I thought to myself, "Hey, why don't I just add the package repositories and install `kali-linux-full`? That totally won't have any problems." So I did just that.

After a look through of the packages when it finished, I immediately decided that, in hindsight, Kali was not for me. I uninstalled the packages installed by it, force-fixed all the dependencies, and upgraded installations back to the typical Raspbian packages.

Some interesting things happened though:

[image: logout sign]

This is the message I am greeted with when attempting to log out. Note that it says `kali-rolling`, NOT `raspbian`. I have not encountered any issues yet, I monitor my auth.log daily, and it has gone through multiple restarts without any issues.

Are there any possible problems I may run into in the future/is my computer at risk (worried mostly about SSH and HTTP, as they are the only out-of-LAN accessible ports)?

### Relevant information:

```
>> cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Kali
DISTRIB_RELEASE=kali-rolling
DISTRIB_CODENAME=kali-rolling
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2016.1"
VERSION_ID="2016.1"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.kali.org/"
```

Comment: So is it setup as 2 different ones on 2 different partitions or equivalent? Or did you override it with `kali`?

Comment: I overrode it with kali. The same partition, same computer.

Comment: ***YOU CROSSED THE STREAMS***. naw, its likely to be fine.. though reinstalling is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Kali's a debian derivative iirc and my guess is in addition to installing packages, it had a few (poorly written?) install scripts that renamed things.

I see a few potential issues - cat /etc/*-release being changed means that any script that tries to identify the system will fail. This also may indicate your system is in an *inconsistent state* and software installs may fail or work oddly.

As for "Are there any possible problems I may run into in the future/is my computer at risk (worried mostly about SSH and HTTP, as they are the only out-of-LAN accessible ports)?"

Just check the relevant setting files to see if they're sane.